# Range seek bar crashing

Tags: android, graph

Seek bar is crashing when I'm forcing both seek thumbs to merge. There should be **at least 6 days interval between seek thumbs and they shouldn't merge at all.** I guess I need some kind of Exception handler, can't figure out where and how though. I appreciate any help to solve this issue.

```
private void moveBar(int left_start, int right_start, boolean direction) {
    if (direction) {
        // check if slider has reached maximum value
        if (realmResults.size() != right_start) {
            // move right
            seekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(right_start + 1);
            seekBar.setSelectedMinValue(left_start + 1);
        }
    } else {
        // check if slider has reached minimum value
        if (left_start != 0) {
            seekBar.setSelectedMaxValue(right_start - 1);
            seekBar.setSelectedMinValue(left_start - 1);
        }
    }
}
```